# Unable to load balance grpc services using nginx ingress on Docker desktop

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx-ingress, grpc-dotnet

**What happened**:
I have deployed ingress-Nginx using the HELM template. I have deployed a gRpc service and exposed it as ClusterIP service. The [service.yaml](https://github.com/VenkateshSrini/Grpc-File-Service/blob/main/gRpc.File.Service/file-grpc-service.yaml) can be seen. This gRpc service does not need any certificate. I have also created a [Kubernetes Ingress](https://github.com/VenkateshSrini/Grpc-File-Service/blob/main/gRpc.File.Service/file-grpc-ing.yaml). All these objects are getting created successfully. Below is the observation

#### Error while accessing the client

Grpc.Core.RpcException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ReturnHttp2Connection(Http2Connection connection, Boolean isNewConnection)

#### Ingress pod logs

I0109 02:18:30.699832       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-6f7bd4bcfb-wchw5", UID:"bc4c59da-f378-421c-a12a-87d46fb6371d", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"592645", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0109 02:18:37.595244       7 controller.go:1112] Service "grpc/grpc-file-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
W0109 02:18:40.928869       7 controller.go:1112] Service "grpc/grpc-file-service" does not have any active Endpoint.

```
In the second task, we can see that Nginx is not able to locate it. But the service exists in the namespace as the ingress
```

NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/grpc-file-service   ClusterIP   10.104.122.174   <none>        5288/TCP   13h

NAME                          ENDPOINTS                         AGE
endpoints/grpc-file-service   10.1.21.65:5288,10.1.21.66:5288   13h

```
**What you expected to happen**:

The gRPC handshake should happen. No error should happen


**NGINX Ingress controller version** (exec into the pod and run nginx-ingress-controller --version.):
```

---

NGINX Ingress controller
Release:       v1.5.1
Build:         d003aae913cc25f375deb74f898c7f3c65c06f05
Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
nginx version: nginx/1.21.6

---

```
**Kubernetes version** (use `kubectl version`):
```

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.2", GitCommit:"5835544ca568b757a8ecae5c153f317e5736700e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-09-21T14:33:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.0", GitCommit:"4ce5a8954017644c5420bae81d72b09b735c21f0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-05-03T13:38:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

```
**Environment**:

- **Cloud provider or hardware configuration**: Local
- **OS** (e.g. from /etc/os-release): Widows 11
- **Kernel** (e.g. `uname -a`): NA
- **Install tools**: The cluster was created in Docker for Desktop kubernetes enabled (version Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002) )
 
- **Basic cluster related info**:
  - `kubectl version`
  `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.2", GitCommit:"5835544ca568b757a8ecae5c153f317e5736700e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-09-21T14:33:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.0", GitCommit:"4ce5a8954017644c5420bae81d72b09b735c21f0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-05-03T13:38:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`
  
- **How was the ingress-nginx-controller installed**:
  - HELM
     - `helm ls -A | grep -i ingress`
          ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx   1               2023-01-08 10:57:42.322980739 +0530 IST deployed        ingress-nginx-4.4.2     
         1.5.1
    -  helm -n <ingresscontrollernamepspace> get values <helmreleasename>
  USER-SUPPLIED VALUES: null

 - command used to install ingress
```

helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace

```
- **Current State of the controller**:
- `kubectl describe ingressclasses`
```

```
  Name:         nginx
  Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
                app.kubernetes.io/version=1.5.1
                helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-4.4.2
  Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
                meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
  Controller:   k8s.io/ingress-nginx
  Events:       <none>
```